# Obtener mensaje que retorna un WebApi en MVC C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy consumiendo un webApi con c#, el webApi en su método de agregar regresa un mensaje según se haya realizado la inserción, lo atrapo con un viewBag pero solo me muestra el status de la transaccion a la BD, ¿como puedo obtener del webApi el mensaje que regresa?, así es como consumo el método

```html
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(EmpModel e)
        {
            string Baseurl = "http://localhost:15105/";

            using (var client =new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync("api/Home/AddRow", stringContent);

                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    ViewBag.Hola = res.RequestMessage;
                }
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo haces, solo lees el mensaje de la petición `Request`.

Hazlo de esta manera:

```
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync("api/Home/AddRow", stringContent);

    if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string apiResponse = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ViewBag.Hola = apiResponse;
    }
```